# need to convert the following neo4j v2.x sample code to neo4j 3.0. I am having issues with the new syntax

Tags: javascript, neo4j

//neo4jv2.X Javascript code segment from ConPanna tutorial. Can someone assist in converting this segment to bolt-Neo4j 3.0?

```
 User.get = function (id, callback) {
        var qp = {
            query: [
                'MATCH (user:User)',
                'WHERE ID(user) = {userId}',
                'RETURN user',
            ].join('\n'),
            params: {
                userId: parseInt(id)
            }
        }

        db.cypher(qp, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, result[0]['user']);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "pwd"));
 var session = driver.session();

 User.get = function (id, callback) {
        var qp = {
            query: [
                'MATCH (user:User)',
                'WHERE ID(user) = {userId}',
                'RETURN user',
            ].join('\n'),
            params: {
                userId: parseInt(id)
            }
        }

        session.run(qp).then(function (result) {
            callback(null, result[0]['user']);
        }).catch(callback);
    };
```